# Json parser converting null values to 0

Tags: java, null, json

I am using net.sf.json library and using it to parse my refMap like:

```
Map<String, Group> myMap = new HashMap<String,Group>();
myMap = this.getGroupValues();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.putAll(refMap);
File jsonFile = new File("./TempJson.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(jsonFile);
fileWriter.write(jsonObj.toString());
```

where my Group class is defined as:

```
class Group {
Double val;
Integer num;
Section sectionObj;
//..getters & setters
}
```

**The Problem is** `this.getGroupValues()` returns some Group objects where **val/num** (wrapper classes) values are 'null' and then JsonObject parser converts it to 0 like:  `"val":0,"num":0`

while if `sectionObj` is null , parser keeps it as null as `"sectionObj":null`

How to get null values for wrapper class Objects too in json file ?

Comment: Show a complete example, please.

Comment: This is valid behavior for JSON, a number cannot be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a different JSON library. For example, [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) will leave `null` values out of the serialized JSON text. When it is deserialized by GSON, those missing values are set to `null` in the new object.

Consider this example:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        final String json = gson.toJson(new Group());

        System.out.println(json);

        Group g = gson.fromJson(json, Group.class);
        System.out.println(g);
    }

    public static class Group {
        Double val;
        Integer num;
        Section sectionObj;
       // Getters and setters...

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "val: '" + val + "' num: '" + num
                    + "' sectionObj: '" + sectionObj + "'";
        }
    }

    public static class Section {}
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
{}
val: 'null' num: 'null' sectionObj: 'null'
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear, will test it. Will json.simple library do that ?

Comment: @pxm I've never used `json.simple`, but the docs make it look like you would have to do object serialization and deserialization by hand, whereas Jackson and Gson would do it automatically. (I might have missed something in my 1 minute overview of `json.simple`, however.)